# View Achive with Category Filter, but Page per post not working

Tags: query-posts

WordPress Version: 3.3.2

Assumption,
My post in category 7 have 9 posts during October 2012.

by accessing

> www.example.com/2012/10/?cat=7

I am able to view all in one page. No issue,
however, I create custom page `category-7.php` in theme folder.

```
//listed category per page = 6
$query = 'posts_per_page=6&cat=7';
$year = get_query_var('year');
if($year > 0)
{
    //build query string
    $query .= '&year='.$year;
}
$month = get_query_var('monthnum');
if($month > 0)
{
    $query .= '&monthnum='.$month;
}
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
if($paged > 0)
{
    $query .= '&paged='.$paged;
}
query_posts($query);
```

Now I access again

> www.example.com/2012/10/?cat=7

The bottom got Next Page option, but when I click it to

> www.example.com/2012/10/page/2/?cat=7

I got ***"404 - Page not found!"***

The only solution I can do is go to WP-Admin, **Reading Settings** change the **"Blog pages show at most"** variable to 6, then I got the correct output.

However, as I research in the wordpress page, by added `query_posts` parameter, it should be work correctly.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're stomping the main query by using `query_posts()`. Don't do that.

Instead, *filter* the main query via `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse82113_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_category( 7 ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '6' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse82113_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Hi, this code is required add to functions.php, as I am using premium wordpress theme, it will affect when I do the theme upgrade. Is it possible way I can do in category-7.php, so it is independence?

Comment: Using a commercial Theme or not should make no difference. You can put this in a Child Theme `functions.php` file, or you can use a custom, site-functionality Plugin, and put it there. But a `pre_get_posts` filter callback should *never* be put in the template file, because by the time the template is loaded, the query has already been run, and the posts have already been fetched.

Comment: Thanks Chip Bennett, I learn a lot from you. As you said never put in the template file, but in the beginner you mention can put in child Theme file, so which one is better? I am still new in WordPress, do you have any more tutorial or learning site regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: In a Child Theme, you *still* wouldn't put it in the template file, but rather in the Child Theme's **`functions.php`** file. But I would go with a **site-functionality Plugin** as the better solution. [Here's a tutorial](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin/) for creating a site functionality Plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, My understanding the template file means functions.php (one of the template file), actually you are refering to Child Theme. I will use site-functionality Plugin. Thank you so much Chop Bennett, have a nice day!

Comment: Usually, when referring to WordPress Themes, a *template* file is a file used to *render the front-end output*, as found in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Anything else is either a *template-part* file (called from within a template file), or else a *functional* file (`functions.php`, or any file included in `functions.php`, that defines Theme *functions/functionality*).